# Shading a segment between two lines on polar axis (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently, I have a plot with lines indicating the orientation of sunrise (blue), midday (red), sunset (orange), and an object (green). I want to create a yellow shaded area between sunrise and sunset. I thought of the `plt.fill` method but that didnt seem to work when I added `plt.fill_between(theta1, theta2, R1, alpha=0.2)`. I think that is because the two lines do not intersect. My current polar axis plot looks like:

[image]

The relevant part of the script is:

```
    #for object
    theta0 = np.deg2rad([190, 190])
    print ("theta0= %s" %theta0)    
    R0 = [0,0.4]

    #for sunrise
    theta1 = np.deg2rad([105, 105])
    print ("theta1= %s" %theta1)    
    R1 = [0,1]

    #for sunset
    theta2 = np.deg2rad([254, 254])
    print ("theta2= %s" %theta2)    
    R1 = [0,1]

    #for midday 
    theta3 = np.deg2rad([0.2, 0.2])
    print ("theta3= %s" %theta3)    
    R3 = [0,1]

    ax.set_theta_zero_location("S")
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    ax.plot(theta1,R1, theta2, R1, theta0, R0, lw=5)

    #plt.fill_between(theta1, theta2, R1, alpha=0.2) #does not work


    plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

I also thought of using the azimuth of the midday and then using the width, calculated from the angle difference between sunset and sunrise and then using these to generate the shaded area. How can I go about doing that? I would like just a yellow shaded area between sunrise and sunset, hence I thought generating `width` from the theta of midday would be a good idea. I tried doing a duplicate of `ax` to form `ax2` which I can then potentially use it to show the `width` (shaded area) of midday. But with the addition of `ax2`, it seem to mess up the plot. How else can I resolve this?

Comment: Where exactly should the yellow region appear in the plot?

Comment: Between the blue and orange lines, which are sunrise and sunset respectively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use fill_between on a polar plot, you have to call it as

```
plt.fill_between(angles_to_go_through, minimum_radii, maximum_radii)
```

So for example, filling between 0 and 90 degrees would be

```
ax.fill_between(
    np.linspace(0, pi/2, 100),  # Go from 0 to pi/2
    0,                          # Fill from radius 0
    1,                          # To radius 1
)
```

This would produce a plot like

[image: polar fill]

In your case, you would call

```
ax.fill_between(
    np.linspace(theta1[0], theta2[0], 100),  # Need high res or you'll fill a triangle
    0,
    1,
    alpha=0.2,
    color='y',
)
```

Comment: Thanks bheklir for your explanation and suggestion. I've got the shaded area now. However, the shaded area seems to be on the wrong side of the plot (at the top instead of the bottom). What can I do to tell the script to shade the other arc? I was thinking that midday can be used to inform the script of where the shaded area should be. Would that be a feasible approach? If so, how can I potentially use midday (indicated by red line) to tell the `plt.fill` function to shade between sunrise and sunset through midday?

Comment: @Craver2000 I think I misunderstood, do you want to fill the arc representing daytime or nighttime?  If it's the latter, then you'll just have to change the `np.linspace` call a bit.  If you go from `theta2[0]` to `theta1[0] + pi`, that should fill the longer arc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was also thinking of a scenario where if I have a day where theta2 is say 260 and theta 1 is 350 (still less than 360), would the addition of pi to theta1 affect the shaded area? The reason I am asking is that I am developing a script that would continue to work throughout the variations of the sun movement at different times/place.

Comment: That would affect things, yes.  You could try to develop some complicated expression to account for this, or you could just use a quick if statement to check for that sort of case.

Comment: Ok, will try that.